# Parametrize a Variety in Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

I'm trying to parametrize the projective variety of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2yz-2xz$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

---

**Progress**:

I know it'll need to be in two pieces, an affine piece and the piece at infinity (which will be in $\mathbb{P}^1$).

Piece at infinity: I think the piece at infinity will end up of the form $[x,y,0]$ but I'm not sure how to find those first two coordinates.

Affine piece: I'm not sure how to parametrize the affine piece aside from it (I think) being of the form $[x,y,1]$.

Comment: You are saying that the points at infinite will have the form [x,y,0]: well, can you tell me what points of that form satisfy the equation of the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You complete the square and you dont have to do the affine and infinity line separately, this is unnatural.

So complete the $x$, square:
$$=[x^2-2(y+z)x]+y^2+z^2-2yz=(x-y-z)^2-4yz$$
So you have $$(x-y-z)^2=4yz$$

This is parameterized as 
$$x-y-z=2st$$
$$y=t^2$$
$$z=s^2$$ and solving the first for $x$, 
$$x=t^2+2st+s^2=(t+s)^2.$$